# Qt Scale image after maximizing window

Tags: c++, qt, events, qt4

I want to change the image scale depending on the size of the `qgraphicsview`.

My current code scales the image, if the window is re-sized, but not if the window is maximized.

```
bool EnlargedView::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (ui.graphicsView == object && (event->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange || event->type() == QEvent::Resize)) {
        scalePicture();
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(object, event);
}
```

I think it is because of the event `WindowStateChange` is called, when the maximize button is clicked, and not after the window is maximized (which happens later).

Any ideas, how to scale the image after maximization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use QWidget::resizeEvent
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent

It gets called after the new geometry is set so you will have the correct geometry to scale with.